# Is there any automation tool I can use to automate resigning iOS app in CN1

Tags: codenameone

I am using a Notification Service Extension to implement end-to-end push notification encryption in CN1. To do this, I download the source, edit it with xCode, and export a new build. I have to create a new extension each time I create a new CN1 build

Likewise, I also have to manually add all of my app's additional non-english languages via xCode each time after I create a CN1 build, as CN1's server automatically signs apps with only english (I don't think there is a build hint that helps with this)

Does someone know of a tool that can be used to automate these steps? Otherwise doing these tasks after creating a CN1 build can be quite time-consuming. Perhaps there is a command-line scripting language I haven't heard of. TBH I haven't done much research on this and would really appreciate hearing an experienced opinion that points me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: The right thing to do would be to enhance Codename One to support at least some of these things as it's the actual automation tool here. Your question really relates to iOS/xcode native

Comment: That would be great, at least for the languages bit. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this done with the help of the app called "cliclick". It automates clicks and keyboard inputs. It's a bit of a rudimentary approach as you have to guesstimate how long you have to wait getween user inputs but it will save me tones of time in the future